# How to return a position of elements in a list using only positive number?

Tags: python, list

I created a list for the user to enter a number, which is the position of the elements in the list, but it still work for negative number. Are there anyway to stop the program taking in negative numbers and accept only positive ones?

Preferably not using conditional statements.

Here is my code:

```
userInput = int(input("Please enter a number from 0-4: "))
lNation = ["Canada", "Australia", "Japan", "Korea", "USA"]
print ("With",userInput,"you have chosen",lNation[userInput])
```

Comment: Why not using conditional statements?

Comment: "Are there anyway to stop the program taking in negative numbers and accept only positive ones?" Did you try using code to **check** whether the number is negative, and doing something else in that case? "Preferably not using conditional statements." **Why**? That is the appropriate tool for the job. You have a *condition* that you want to impose!

Answer (score 2):

```
def positive_number_between_0_and_4():
    while True:
        try:
           val = int(input("Enter a number(0-4)"))
        except ValueError:
           print("hmm thats not an integer...")
        else:
           if 0 <= val <= 4:
              return val
           print("That number is not between 0 and 4")

choice = positive_number_between_0_and_4()
print(f"You choose: {choice}")
```